# Wordpress posts not updating or publishing

Tags: wordpress, caching, plugins, posting

**Site**: `http://reikas.lt/`

The thing is site was working good all the time, now suddenly whatever I edit(change permalinks, publish/edit post etc.) it does not have effect on the live site, it seems the settings are just not woring and posts are not there.

The second image of a slider was changed, the image ramained, then i deleted the image, it dissapeared after a while but the slide is still there(empty) even though its deleted from backend and new one is added (not appearing).

**Intresting thing**: FTP changes are working and it responds immediately to any CSS/HTML changes

**Extra:**

- Tried disabling plugins
- installing super cache and deleting the cache
- Adding: define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false);
- clearing local caches, but it appears from other computers its the
  same.

Was just wondering maybe hosting cached database.? seems not logical tho.

Comment: I guess it's more that either your server or the browser is caching, not the database. However this sounds a bit like a support question regarding your hosting (e.g. talk with your hoster about the webservers caching settings) or your browser (e.g. contact your browser-vendor for your support options to make out most of your browser). For the programming question: You don't give enough technical information that anything could be answered in concrete, just some comments can be left and some wild assumptions can be run which by chance some of it might enable you to finish trouble-shooting.

Comment: The line I added was added to wp-config, no results anyway. In addition I can change anything - add menus and change anything and the changes will stay in the backend but wont be seen in frontend. The server was never caching like this, and it has been almost a month now and now suddenly..? I don't thing its brwoser related as I  asked other pople to check it and they see the same.

Comment: Perhaps, yes. Just double check with the specs and let me know if there is something in concrete you wonder about: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-13 - For analyzing down on the HTTP level I suggest you to install curl on the command-line and just poke your server a bit with some inspecting requests.

Comment: Turned out to be server caching, thank you!